# Are emoji allowed on Hinduism.StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

Personally I have found people to be rude on many, many SE sites.  On a few occasions I have found that I was misinterpreting the other user's intent. I find that the skillful use of emoji prevents such misunderstandings and leads to an all-around warmer atmosphere.  That is, they can make a sterile place feel more like a community of people who actually care about each other and their ideas.

So, can we use emoji in question and answers?

Comment: Yes as long as it does not offend anyone, for example (mooning) from Skype ;)

Comment: Also don't use too many, use wherever required. otherwise it would look irritating.

Comment: IMO, use of Emojis in the meta site should be OK. In the main site, they should be avoided as they may not add value due to their funny nature.

Comment: I see, so to you they are funny? For me they make the other persons intentions clear. This might be a cultural difference.

Comment: You are right. I have seen users here removing completely harmless "Namaste" and "Thanks" from the posts but the same users are now inserting gifs into their posts without any reasons. I don't understand these double standards. @RubelliteFae

Comment: Related post on MSE: [Do we want emojis in posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299922/241919)

Comment: @Rickross The difference is meta vs main site.

Comment: @Rickross Yes, the first answer I made here I was warned not to use my salutation or to sign off with "Namaste." I thought removing these removed the friendliness I wanted to express, but I have followed the rule since then. It is easy to get emotionally charged about long-held beliefs and I want it to be obvious to people I am not talking down to them.

Comment: @Rickross There are no double standard. Saying double standards for a single gif? Really? Thanks, Namaste etc., are chatty. [They are unnecessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/). It is a SE wide policy. They add nothing to the post. When it comes to main, it is a place where serious discussions take place. Read the question I posted the gif to. It is creating an unhealthy environment on site. Adding some fun in the answers is not a crime. Read answers on Main meta. There are many answers with funny images and gifs in it. No need to say "some users". I know whom you are calling.

Comment: @Rickross It should be allowed everywhere if emojis are not harmless.

Comment: While "They are unnecessary. ... They add nothing to the post" *may* apply to sign-offs. It's a different story with emoji. Understanding a poster's intentions is paramount for a harmonious community. Recently (on another SE) someone accused me of being in a "dark place." I have no idea what led them to such a conclusion, but I believe they would have thought and responded differently had I used emoji. Many people cannot differentiate between arguing "to the man" and "to the idea." Even the word "argue" has negative connotation to the average person rather than the neutral, scholarly use.

Comment: One good point brought up in the discussion @Sarvabhouma linked is that salutations—as they are at the beginning—reduce the useful information that search engines display directly below the link/title.

Comment: Emojis are not displayed on some browsers. They show as blank rectangles. This damages the intent which the user is adding  emojis at first place. They are not shown as same to all the people. They look differently. Many people (including me) don't know exact meanings of some emojis. It is hard to search meaning of each emoji every time while the focus should be on the question or answer posted. Over usage of it will make the post unpleasant. There is already  a canonical post linked by @AndrewT. on meta which gives advantages and disadvantages of using emoji. That can be followed.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Emoji are supported by Apple OS X & iOS, Google Android, Microsoft Windows, emojidex (for web browsers), Samsung devices, LG devices, & HTC devices, (as well as WhatsApp, Facebook, Twitter, & EmojiOne apps). Moreover it is a Unicode standard. This is like saying SE shouldn't use HTML 4.0 because legacy devices might not support it. I have also left my opinion on the MSE thread.

Comment: The emojis are seen different unlike an image or gif. Gif is shown same to everyone. Same :P emoji is shown different on different plat forms. Try yourself on different platforms and different browsers. It takes time what the user want to convey in the post. Unless they are consistent on every browser. It also [show as squares](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234490/357396)  to some users which damages the readability of the post.

Comment: Yes, I can see every version on Emojipedia. The differences are small on the basic faces. Yes, there are many emoji that most people don't know the meaning of, but I think we can all recognize the facial expressions.

Comment: Also, they use fewer characters than words or emoticons—e.g. :-). Judging by emoticons SE people use, the most useful are:  (big smile),  (smile),  (nervous laughter), (mischievous smile),  ("Just kidding"),  ("I wonder"/thinking),  ("I hope"/grimace),  ("I don't believe it"/sarcasm),  (annoyed),  (angry),  ("I'm sorry to hear that"),  (worried),  ("Oh, no!"),  (shocked or scared),  (approve),  (disapprove),  ("please" or "thank you" or "Namaste."),  (applause), ✊ (solidarity), ❤ (love or appreciation),  (Om). Some are obviously only useful in comments.

Comment: The link you posted about squares is four years old. Are there still operating systems that don't support them? They are part of Unicode. The only devices I know which don't support Unicode are CD & DVD players.

Comment: Since my original post I have learned that emoji appeal to me because: ① I have Asperger's and thus reading other people's emotions is harder for me than the average person—nearly impossible in text; and ② I lived in Japan before emoji were released worldwide and therefore am comfortable and familiar with them. Many people use them for meanings other than their original Japanese meanings, which has complicated and somewhat frustrated the issue for me.
This recently popped up in my achievements which is why I'm replying years later.